# What is the equivalent method in People API for ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

In my old App Script, I use the following syntax:

```
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField('tennis', 'Favorite Sport')
```

See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactsbycustomfieldquery,-label).

I am now moving to People API. I can't seem to find the documentation for searching people using [UserDefined](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.UserDefined) values.

What I have found so far is [search by name](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts), not by user defined fields.

This does not search on my user defined fields:

```
var response = People.People.searchContacts({
  query: "tennis",
  readMask: "names,userDefined"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no equivalent in the Advanced People Service for `ContactsApp.getContactsByCustomField`

---

From https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts

> The query matches on a contact's names, nickNames, emailAddresses, phoneNumbers, and organizations fields that are from the CONTACT source.

Regarding "readMask", it is used to specified the fields to be included in the response.

---

Related

- [Is these a good replacement in People API for Contact API search method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68017843/1595451)
- [Appscript/Javascript format for Google People API searchContacts()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69202812/1595451)